# I would like to create an auto-schedule but I have some problems

Tags: schedule

Creating a schedule where I introduce a word and the program returns the info I need is what I want. I mean, if I write the word "monday" I would like a response with the subjects I have that day. I did this (very brief example, I have more subjects):

```
 x = int(input("Day of the week: "))

if x == 2:
    x = 0
    print('9:00-11:00 Biology - Classroom C4B \n11:00-13:00 Maths- Classroom C5')
elif x == 3:
    print('11:00-13:00 Physics - Classroom C4B')
```

This works, but the problem is that I do not want to enter numbers but words. I also tried with **eval** and works too. However, in that case, I must enter a word between '' because **eval** reads strings and that is not what I want. How can I improve my program?

Thanks in advance (Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

And because you do not use [raw_input( )](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-raw_input-examples/)?

`input()` actually evaluates the input as Python code.

And in your code `x = int(input("Day of the week: "))` only accepts numerics inputs.  `raw_input()` returns the verbatim string entered by the user.

```
day = raw_input("Day of the week: ")

if day == "monday":
    print('9:00-11:00 Biology - Classroom C4B \n11:00-13:00 Maths- Classroom C5')

elif day == "tuesday":
    print('11:00-13:00 Physics - Classroom C4B')
```